# Specific text causes a internal server 500 error when posted in html forms

Tags: html, forms

I have a website with a form hosted online. Most of the times I am able to successfully post the form. But on a few occasions, I run into an internal server error when I try to post the form. After troubleshooting, I found that there are specific text inputs that lead to this error. I am able to successfully post the text when I deploy the website on my local server. I also pasted the text into some of the w3schools live html form examples and I got two errors. The first error(When I input part of the text): 'Illegal input'. Second error(when I input the whole text):  This www.w3schools.com page can’t be found.

Is this a problem with the server configuration or something that has to do with the input text?
(I want allowed to paste the input text along with the question. It apparently looks like spam)

Answer (score 1):

First I would like to thank everyone who attempted to help me with this problem. It turns out the problem was being caused by the Mod Security module on the cpanel. I got the idea [here](https://www.simplemachines.org/community/index.php?topic=234628.0). I disabled the module and things worked.

Mod Security offers an extra layer of security to your website. I do not think that disabling mod security is the ultimate best solution but I think it is one that works. I hear that one can tweak the settings as opposed to disabling it but that is a solution I still have to look up.